# How can you solve the equation for a non-concentric cylindrical capacitor?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, capacitance

I am having some trouble figuring out how to start this problem, I know in order to solve the problem itself I have to find an answer to Laplace's equation, that will give me the potential of the system and from there it is direct, but I am not quite sure of the best way to start solving for Laplace's equation itself, given that both cylinders making the capacitor are not in the same center.

Comment: Have you learned about conformal mapping?

Comment: Sure, however, I was hoping to find a way to solve it without the transformation